# Error while deploying Drools workbench 7.7.0.Final with wildFly11

Tags: drools-guvnor, kie-workbench, wildfly-11, kie-wb, drools-kie-workbench

I've downloaded latest version of kie-workbench 7.7.0 which is compatible with wildFly-11 . Kept kie-workbench-7.7.0.war into deployments folder of wildFly 11. Starting from bin folder using following command standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml. Then I'm getting the following issue. Can anyone say what I'm doing wrong here? If I take older version of kie-workbench 6.5.0 with wildFly10 it's working fine.I'm doing this in Windows10 OS. Thanks in advance.

```
19:16:43,847 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kie-wb: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kie-wb: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory: D:\downloads\drools%20workbench7\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp7606482f82f9e84e\content-3e547a5371ce9421
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory: D:\downloads\drools%20workbench7\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp7606482f82f9e84e\content-3e547a5371ce9421
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:241)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory: D:\downloads\drools%20workbench7\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp7606482f82f9e84e\content-3e547a5371ce9421
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.plugins.engine.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:79)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.plugins.PluginService.init(PluginService.java:79)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.plugins.PluginStartup.contextInitialized(PluginStartup.java:32)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:205)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory: D:\downloads\drools%20workbench7\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp7606482f82f9e84e\content-3e547a5371ce9421
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.validateListFilesParameters(FileUtils.java:536)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:512)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:684)
```

Comment: Please click on help, take the tour of the site, learn how to ask a question and present the information we'll need to help you address your issue. Then you will have a shot at getting the help you need. Otherwise it's a crapshoot for you. We're not mind readers here.

Comment: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory: - Does the directory exist? What is the parameter directory?

Comment: @NOTiFY Yes It exists. I've kept drools workbench 7.7.0 war into wildfly-11 deployments folder and starting using following command, standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml

Comment: Can somebody help me out here? It's urgent.